# Is it possible to open a new URL in Safari from Chrome if the page is being viewed on an iOS device?

Tags: javascript

Let’s say I have a webpage and it has a button with [an `HREF` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/href). I want the `HREF` of that button to be opened on Safari browser if the button is being clicked from an iOS device, even if the user is accessing the page on Google Chrome.

As of now, I only need to handle this situation for Chrome and not any generic browser. The way I see it, there are two parts to the problem:

- **Identifying the OS of the Client Machine**: This I might be able to do easily.
- **Opening the Popup on Safari from Chrome**: This is the tricky part I am not sure if it is possible.

I am looking for possibilities of accomplishing the second part.

Comment: Not to my knowledge, no. Why do you want to?

Comment: Safari has an easily detectable user agent, so I'd suggest just detecting it and displaying a message instead of the link, i.e. "Please open in Safari instead"

Comment: Where exactly does that message get displayed? Inside the webpage like a button? That would exactly be what I am trying to accomplish but how ?

Comment: That's entirely up to you. JavaScript can be used to make a message show up based on user agent - what it looks like and how it acts is under your control.

Comment: @JakeGould It's *conceivably* possible - a browser could register a custom URL scheme like `chrome://` or `mozilla://`. Would be a UX nightmare for folks *without* those browsers installed, though. Probably why none of the major vendors implemented such a thing.

Answer (score 3):

**Short Answer**: no.

**Long Answer**: Some iOS apps [have defined URL schemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html) that can be used to access the app directly from the browser. For example, `twitter://timeline`. But Safari for iOS does not have one.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the OS the user is using and if it Chrome then suggest the user to open it in Safari and also provide the link where to download it from. Or you can also suggest the user to make safari their default browser. ( Also provide a link on how to do that to them).